# Can I mirror my iPad's display using the VGA adapter for use in a presentation?

Tags: ipad, ios, vga-adapter

I would love to be able to mirror the display of my iPad on a projector for use in a presentation. Is there any software available to do this - on the AppStore or if necessary for use with a jailbroken iPad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no official way to achieve this.

You have to jailbreak your iPad and use a software like [DisplayOut](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayout/) (works on all iDevices) to do this.

Comment: Wow - that was faster than I expected. :-)

Comment: At your service, Sir.

Answer (score 3):

Just for clarification:

With the iPad2, every app is mirrored on the VGA adapter by default, without any additional measures.

Answer (score 2):

As Studer mentioned, there is no official way to do so. you can use the DisplayOut software for Jailbroken iPads.

If you're more developer oriented, there is also 
[this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662201/ipad-vga-connector-mirror-screen-in-own-application)